# TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I suddenly started getting this error out of nowhere with weeks of no problems and I can't seem to find out what's causing it.
Here is the full error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at getFullNumber (C:\Bots\Cafe\Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0\commands\opt.js:13:31)
    at init (C:\Bots\Cafe\Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0\commands\opt.js:149:20)
    at Request._callback (C:\Bots\Cafe\Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0\commands\opt.js:139:25)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Bots\Cafe\Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Bots\Cafe\Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Bots\Cafe\Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
```

It seems to be pointing at the functions.

```
 function getFullNumber(cash){
        var newcash = -1;
        if(!isNaN(Number(cash))){
            newcash = Number(cash);
        } else {
            var suffix = cash.substr(cash.length-1);
            suffix = suffix.toLocaleUpperCase();
            switch(suffix){
                case "K":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000;
                    break;
                case "T":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000000;
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000000000;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return newcash;
    }
```

and

```
function init(cash){
    try {
        cash = getFullNumber(cash);
        if(cash <= 0) return;
        var userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(client.config.dataFolder + "/users/" + currentUser + ".json", "utf8"));
        var arr = getMaxItems(userData, cash);
        if(arr){
            if(arr.length==0){
                client.users.get(currentUser).send("You Need More Cash!");
            } else {
                var text = ahk(arr);
                var file = client.config.dataFolder + "/ahks/" + getFileName();
                fs.writeFileSync(file, text);
                client.users.get(currentUser).send({
                      files: [{
                          //attachment: 'C:/Bots/Cafe/Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0/test.ahk',
                        attachment: file,
                        name: 'Ahk-' + displayTime() +'.ahk'
                      }]
                    });
            }
        }
        //if(str.length>0)
            //client.users.get(currentUser).send(str + "\n`++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++`");
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

not sure why this started happening out of the blue but any help would be fantastic!

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    var currentUser = message.author.id;
    var file = client.config.dataFolder + "/users/" + currentUser + ".json";
    if(!fs.existsSync(file)) return;
    //convert numbers with K,M,B,T to real numbers
    function getFullNumber(cash){
        var newcash = -1;
        if(!isNaN(Number(cash))){
            newcash = Number(cash);
        } else {
            var suffix = cash.substr(cash.length-1);
            suffix = suffix.toLocaleUpperCase();
            switch(suffix){
                case "K":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000;
                    break;
                case "T":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000000;
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000000000;
                    break;
                    
            }
                        
        }
        return newcash;
    }
    function addSuffix(num){
        if(num<1000)return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)).toString();
        else if(num<1000000) return parseFloat((num/1000).toFixed(2)).toString() + "K";
        else if(num<1000000000) return parseFloat((num/1000000).toFixed(2)).toString() + "M";
        else if(num<1000000000000) return parseFloat((num/1000000000).toFixed(2)).toString() + "B";
        else if(num<1000000000000000) return parseFloat((num/1000000000000).toFixed(2)).toString() + "T";
        else return parseFloat((num/1000000000000000).toFixed(2)).toString() + "Q";
    }
    function decaf(items){
        var decafItems = ["Brewer","Grinder","Shelving","Wifi","Ice-Machine","Blender","Table","Dishwasher"];
        var decafObj = {};
        for(var item in items){
            if (decafItems.includes(item))
                decafObj[item] = items[item];
        }
        return decafObj;
    }
    //return a string list of items with count
    //as per the cash you have
    function getMaxItems(userData, cash, first){
        var allItems = ["Brewer","Grinder","Shelving","Wifi","Ice-Machine","Blender","Table","Dishwasher","Seat","Espresso","Boiler","Wastebin","Refrigerator","Infuser","Sofa","Dispenser","Creamer","Press","Pitcher","Urn","Airpot","Sleeve-Holder","Warmers","Spigot","Juicer","Teapot","Pump","Delivery","Grill","Knock-Box","Spice-Rack","Hoppers","Toaster","Oven","Microwave","Farm","Transport","Solar","Radio"];
        var uData = userData.list == 'decaf' ? decaf(userData.items) : userData.items;
        
        var best = getCalculatedBest(uData, cash);
        if(best == "")
            return [];
        uData[best].count++;
        var obj = {};
        obj[best] = {count:1};
        var amount = 0;
        while(amount < cash){
            amount += (uData[best].count-1)*client.config.items[best].increment + client.config.items[best].basePrice;
            best = getCalculatedBest(uData, cash - amount);
            //if there are no items left to buy with the left cash amount
            if(best == "") break;
            
            uData[best].count++;
            if(!obj[best])obj[best] = {count:0};
            obj[best].count++;
        }
        var arrItems = [];
        for(var item in obj){
            arrItems.push({name :item, data: obj[item]});
        }
        arrItems.sort(function(a,b){
            return allItems.indexOf(a.name) - allItems.indexOf(b.name);
        });
        var strArr = [];
        for(var i in arrItems)
            strArr.push(".b " + arrItems[i].name + " " + arrItems[i].data.count);
        return strArr;
    }
    //get the best item to buy by increments calculation
    function getCalculatedBest(uData, cash){
        var min = {
            name: '',
            cpsPer: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
        };
        var firstZero = true;
        for(var name in uData){
            if(uData[name].count==0){
                if(firstZero)
                    firstZero = false;
                else 
                    continue;
            }
            uData[name].price = uData[name].count *client.config.items[name].increment + client.config.items[name].basePrice;
            //check only the items that have prices lower than the opt cash
            if(uData[name].price<=cash)
                if(uData[name].price/uData[name].cps < min.cpsPer){
                    min.cpsPer = uData[name].price/uData[name].cps;
                    min.name = name;
                }
        }
        return min.name;
    }
    //get the cash using the api
    function getUserInfo(){
        try{
            request(
                {
                    url : "https://the-kirb.club/api/u/" + currentUser,
                    headers : {
                        "Authorization" : client.config.apikey
                    }
                },
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if(body){
                        var data = JSON.parse(body);
                        init(data.cash);
                    }
                }
            );
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    function getFileName(){
        var dd = new Date();
        return dd.getFullYear().toString()+dd.getMonth().toString()+dd.getUTCDate().toString()+
            dd.getMinutes().toString()+dd.getSeconds().toString() + dd.getMilliseconds().toString() +
            (Math.random()*100).toFixed(0) + ".ahk";
    }

   
    function ahk(arr){
        var str = '#SingleInstance,force\n';
        str += 'Your_List:= ' + JSON.stringify(arr) + "\n";
        str += '*f3::\n';
        str += '    For,k,v in Your_List\n';
        str += '        {\n';
        str += '            SendInput,% Your_List[k]\n';
        str += '            SendInput {Enter}\n';
        str += '            Sleep,5500\n';
        str += '        }\n';
        str += 'esc::Exitapp\n';
        str += '    return';

        return str;
    }

        function displayTime() {
    var str = "";

    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds
    }
    str += hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
    if(hours > 11){
        str += "PM"
    } else {
        str += "AM"
    }
    return str;
}


    function init(cash){
        try {
            cash = getFullNumber(cash);
            if(cash <= 0) return;
            var userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(client.config.dataFolder + "/users/" + currentUser + ".json", "utf8"));
            var arr = getMaxItems(userData, cash);
            if(arr){
                if(arr.length==0){
                    client.users.get(currentUser).send("You Need More Cash!");
                } else {
                    var text = ahk(arr);
                    var file = client.config.dataFolder + "/ahks/" + getFileName();
                    fs.writeFileSync(file, text);
                    client.users.get(currentUser).send({
                          files: [{
                              //attachment: 'C:/Bots/Cafe/Cafe Team Bot ver 2.4.0/test.ahk',
                            attachment: file,
                            name: 'Ahk-' + displayTime() +'.ahk'
                          }]
                        });
                }
            }
            //if(str.length>0)
                //client.users.get(currentUser).send(str + "\n`++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++`");
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    
    if(args.length==0)
        getUserInfo();
    else {
        var cash = args[0];
        init(cash);
    }
}
```

edited to have the whole file.

Comment: also note that old versions suddenly dont work anymore

Answer (score 0):

It seem, init function passing incorrect params to getFullNumber.
Just put some guard to check if the cash is typeof string. Maybe something like

```
else if(typeof cash === 'string') { 
  var suffix = cash.substr(cash.length-1);
  ... 
}
// Let the newcash default value return.
```

---

Edit to include biggest example.

```
    function getFullNumber(cash){
        var newcash = -1;
        if(!isNaN(Number(cash))){
            newcash = Number(cash);
        } 
        else if(typeof cash === 'string') { 
            var suffix = cash.substr(cash.length-1);
            suffix = suffix.toLocaleUpperCase();
            switch(suffix){
                case "K":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000;
                    break;
                case "T":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000000;
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    newcash = Number(cash.substr(0,cash.length-1))*1000000000000000;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return newcash;
    }
```

Comment: that seems to break the code unless im missing an edit i need in there

Comment: oh im an idiot, but unfortunately that dosent work and it dosent pop an error now

Comment: @KyleReeves-Kulpa `if(cash <= 0) return;` the function stop because of that remember

Comment: it rarely ever is, plus it'll return a message if it is.

Comment: im kind of thinking something else is causing this. this code worked for weeks before randomly stopping today.

Comment: @KyleReeves-Kulpa if it still throw an error, then it should not be this code since we already make sure that the cash is not undefined. I what Beginner said it true that in your init function, you return directly is cash less than zero.

Comment: i actually figured out what the problem is after talking to the guy who originally coded it. He has it autoconverting certain numbers based on what the discord api is sending back. The problem is the api isnt returning the information the bot needs to finish the math.